# 2007 honda civic wont start after new battery and starter

Tags: honda, electrical, battery, civic, starter

i have a 2007 honda civic ex 5 speed. so in like a week out of 30 times starting my car it didn't start like 5 times. than it wouldn't start at all.so i tried to pop start it and was fine. so i was thinking  it must be the starter. so i tried  replacing  the starter and battery and it still wont start but i can still pop start it and it runs fine.im not sure what to try next.o cannot find any thing on the internet about it

Comment: do you have any diagnostic tool to check what error code stored on your cars?

Comment: You can take it to AutoZone/O'reilly's and have them test if the alternator is good or not.  If you can jump start it then the starter is fine.  You could use a multimeter to see if the battery seems to be keeping a charge (should stay at 12v).  If it starts fine "immediately after running" then I'd wonder if there's a short somewhere or something else that's draining the battery?  Also after running it the battery should recharge to 12v.  Good luck!

Comment: What do you mean by pop start it? Do you mean push start? Do you hear a click when you turn the ignition switch to start?